# Eliminate multiple of couple of numbers

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have this simple program that create a list of two digit from 1 to 7:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
...
```

and so on.

The condition I want is complicated because I want to EXCLUDE multiples of the two numbers: if I have 1,2 printed I don't want also 2,4 . And so on.

The f90 program is very simple:

```
program multiple
 implicit none
 integer :: i,j


i=0
j=0
 do i= 1,7
 do j =1,7  
 print*, i,j
 end do
 end do   

end program
```

The question is: what `IF` (or other criteria) I must implement to eliminate digits of the form:

```
2 4
2 6
3 6
```

that are the multiples of `1,2 ; 1,3 ; 1,2` ?

Comment: What did *you* try so far?

Answer (score 1):

If the largest value that either digit can take is `7` this ought to work:

1. Rewrite each pair of digits as a rational number with denominator `5040`.  I leave it as an exercise to figure out why I chose that denominator.  So `(2,3)` would become `3360/5040`.  Of course, since the numbers have a common denominator you don't need to store that.
2. Now you have a mapping from your list of pairs to a list of integers; all the pairs which are equivalent by your rule (*ie* `(1,2),(2,4),(3,6), ...`) map to the same integer (in this case `2520`).
3. There is a variety of ways to use this list of integers to write a loop to print only one of the pairs which maps to it.

This should be enough to get you started.  If you have problems turning this into Fortran update your question with your best attempt and I (or someone else) will help you finish it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the specifics, but it's simple enough to just show the general case.

In simple terms, `i` is your "outer loop" and first number, and `j` is your "inner loop" and second number.  If you want to skip pairs containing a specific second number, the `if` goes around the `print statement`.  If you want to skip pairs containing a specific first number, the `if` goes around the inner loop.

*But*, you want to skip the loop if the index is *not* your target value.

To see what both looks like in a program (2, 5, 3, and 6 could be any numbers):

```
do i= 1,7
    if i /= 2 .and. i /=5 then
        do j =1,7
            if j /= 3 .then. j /= 6 then
                print*, i,j
            end if
        end do
    end if
end do
```

So, in this case, you'll only execute the `j` loop when `i` isn't 2 or 5.  When you execute the inner loop, it will only print when `j` isn't 3 or 6.

Comment: @ John C thanks for your tip but i suppose your code only exclude numbers from the first and second cycle. My condition is a bit more complicated because i want to exclude multiple of the two numbers: if i have 1,2 printed i don't want also 2,4 . And so on.

Comment: In that case, you'll need the second `if` to test values of both `i` and `j`. Keep in mind that you can do math, too. Oh, and I found an excellent [set of notes](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/select.html) on Fortran 90 that might help.

Comment: Yes i see the notes but its not help me so much. Yes the condition on i and j must be a math condition something like `if(i/j .ne. m*(i/j)) then` in this case i must use another index that compute me the muliplicity of the numbers: `m`-times i/j.

Comment: Think of it backwards. How do you know that the current value of `i` is a multiple of some `n`? Yes, it's because `n *` some number `.eq. i`, but the opposite `i/n` is useful, too. (There's a built-in function that solves the problem, but I don't know if it's permissible.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to declare an array of logicals, such as

```
logical, dimension(7,7) :: found
```

Set every element to `.false.`.  Then read your list of pairs of numbers.  When you encounter a pair such as `(2,4)` you first reduce the fraction it represents (*ie* to `(1,2)`), then you set the corresponding element of `found` to `.true.`.

After one run through your list of pairs of integers the array `found` contains `.true.` at precisely those locations whose indices are the pairs you are looking for.

This doesn't quite work if your list contains, say, `(2,4)` and `(3,6)` but not `(1,2)` and your desired output is `(2,4)`, that is the first of the pairs which occurs.  But I expect you could adapt it for this situation too.